# How to make jquery mouseenter affect only one DIV

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I'm new to jquery. I'm building a image portfolio.
Basically i have 2 div classes. And inside the main class i have an image.
When i enter with my mouse on the main DIV, i get the second div to animate.
It works good, but when i copy the main DIV 2 or more time, on MOUSEENTER every DIV is triggered. How can i make that only the DIV that mouse is on to trigger, and that the others stay unaffected. Thank you.
I will give you both my jquery and html code. And provide an image of what my problem is.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".blue").animate({
            left: '0px',
            opacity: '0.6',

        }, "slow");
    })

    $(".main").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".blue").animate({
            left: '-250px',
            opacity: '1.0',

        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;background:#cecece;height:100px;width:350px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="blue" style="background:#09bbfd;z-index:100;height:100px;width:250px;left:-250px;position:absolute;opacity:0.5;">
    </div>

    <a href="#">
        <img src="uploads/windows.jpg" alt="windows">
    </a>
</div>
```

[The problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTsJN.jpg)

Comment: Consider using [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to accomplish this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** to combine both event handler. Also set `this` context to select `.blue` div inside the hovered element. Use **[`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** for clearing the animation queue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main").hover(function() {
    $(".blue", this).stop().animate({
      left: '0px',
      opacity: '0.6',
    }, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $(".blue", this).stop().animate({
      left: '-250px',
      opacity: '1.0',
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;background:#cecece;height:100px;width:350px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="blue" style="background:#09bbfd;z-index:100;height:100px;width:250px;left:-250px;position:absolute;opacity:0.5;">
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="uploads/windows.jpg" alt="windows">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;background:#cecece;height:100px;width:350px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="blue" style="background:#09bbfd;z-index:100;height:100px;width:250px;left:-250px;position:absolute;opacity:0.5;">
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="uploads/windows.jpg" alt="windows">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .find() or pass the context to find the `blue` element relative to the hovered element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".blue").stop().animate({
      left: '0px',
      opacity: '0.6',
    }, "slow");

  })

  $(".main").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".blue").stop().animate({
      left: '-250px',
      opacity: '1.0',
    }, "slow");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;background:#cecece;height:100px;width:350px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="blue" style="background:#09bbfd;z-index:100;height:100px;width:250px;left:-250px;position:absolute;opacity:0.5;">
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="uploads/windows.jpg" alt="windows">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;background:#cecece;height:100px;width:350px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="blue" style="background:#09bbfd;z-index:100;height:100px;width:250px;left:-250px;position:absolute;opacity:0.5;">
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="uploads/windows.jpg" alt="windows">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;background:#cecece;height:100px;width:350px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="blue" style="background:#09bbfd;z-index:100;height:100px;width:250px;left:-250px;position:absolute;opacity:0.5;">
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="uploads/windows.jpg" alt="windows">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, consider using `hover()` or chain the events.